# gemspec で、どこにも push できないようにする方法は？

Tags: ruby, rubygems

普段 ruby で開発をしていると、 OSS化できるものは公開 gem へ、個人で使うプロジェクトを跨いだ共通処理は private gem へ、それぞれ切り出して開発を行っています。

このように開発を行う場合、手元で `rake release` は、少なくとも public gem を開発している場合においては、 release が可能な状態になります。

一方、 private な gem においては、 `rake release` は実行する予定はひとまずないのですが、ついうっかり、これを実行してしまった場合に、 rubygems.org にリリースされて、全世界に公開されてしまうのは、防ぎたいなと思っています。

## 質問

- private な gem を開発している場合に、どこにも release できないような gemspec 記述は、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
spec.metadata['allowed_push_host']
```

に存在しないホストを設定するとか。

<kbd>bundle gem</kbd> で雛形を作成すると `"TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"` という値になっています。

[Serving your own gems](https://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/#serving-your-own-gems)